# java reader clasloader/ after export not working

Tags: java, classloader, reader

Trying to add some info about my project and..this is my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class InfoView extends JDialog {

ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
File fileChange = new File(classLoader.getResource("changelog.txt").getFile());
File fileTodo = new File(classLoader.getResource("TODO.txt").getFile());
File filePoradnik = new File(classLoader.getResource("Poradnik.txt").getFile());
File file;

public InfoView(JFrame frame, boolean b, int a) {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setModal(b);

    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

    JTextArea txtchangelog = new JTextArea();
    txtchangelog.setEditable(false);
    txtchangelog.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(txtchangelog);   
    getContentPane().add(sp);

    switch(a){
    case 0:
        file=filePoradnik;
        break;
    case 1:
        file=fileTodo;
        break;
    case 2:
        file=fileChange;
        break;
    }   

    try
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        txtchangelog.read( br, null );
        br.close();
        txtchangelog.requestFocus();
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e2)
    { System.out.println(e2); }
    //setVisible(true);
    repaint();
}
```

The problem is that when in working in eclipse it works, but when i make jar file it dosen't... Agr Didn't find any solution's...

What is wrong.... trying to read file in jar.......

---

I think i found..

```
  ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
  InputStream fileChange =classLoader.getResourceAsStream("changelog.txt");
   InputStream fileTodo = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("TODO.txt");
   InputStream filePoradnik =classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Poradnik.txt");
   InputStream file;
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
   txtchangelog.read( br, null ); br.close(); 
  txtchangelog.requestFocus();
    file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**It does not work because there is a semantic difference between loading classes from a `ClassLoader` and relatively to a class file:**

1. `ClassLoader.getResource()` will try to load class from the classpath, but if the file exists in the JAR file, it will not be loaded
2. `Class.getResource()` will try to load class relatively to a class file even if it is part of JAR file

**IDEs generally execute code from directories and not JAR files.** You need to use the following code:

```
File fileChange = new File(getClass().getResource("changelog.txt").getFile());
```

Comment: So why that worked:
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

 public ImageIcon ICON_COMPUTER = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("images/my_computer.png"));
?? Still calling classloader and files were in dir in jar file.. But the same method didin't worked..

Comment: I explained in in my answer.